# Can i have multiple layouts in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, layout, modular, zend-layout

I have a flashy page with image rotators in the front end for the clients.

For back-end I want to have different layout. Can i have multiple layout?

A little hint would be appreciable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I create a layout plugin, to switch layouts when a non-default module is called:

```
class MyApplication_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        switch ($request->getModuleName()) {
            case 'admin': $this->_moduleChange('admin');
        }
    }

    protected function _moduleChange($moduleName) {
        $this->getLayout()->setLayoutPath(
            dirname(dirname(
                $this->getLayout()->getLayoutPath()
            ))
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'layouts/scripts/' . $moduleName
        );
        $this->getLayout()->setLayout($moduleName);
    }

}
```

Then in my Bootstrap, I do this:

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc(
            array(
                'layoutPath' => self::$root . '/application/views/layouts/scripts',
                'layout' => 'layout',
                'pluginClass' => 'MyApplication_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout'
            )
        );
```

The non-default layouts go inside a folder named after the module, so my directory structure looks like this:

```
/path/to/application/views/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml --> default layout

/path/to/application/views/layouts/scripts/admin/admin.phtml --> admin layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple layouts though switching them based on the request is not so straight forward.

I've had to do this enough times that I ended up developing a controller action helper and application resource plugin that you're free to use or take inspiration from.

[ModuleLayout Application Resource Plugin](https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/Application/Resource/Modulelayout.php)

[ModuleLayoutLoader Controller Action Helper](https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/Controller/Action/Helper/ModuleLayoutLoader.php)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
//in controller
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layoutName');
```

It will switch layout to layoutName.phtml in your module's view/scripts folder ;)

Comment: This does not work at all. Should be $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layoutname')

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. The line:

```
class MyApplication_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout extends end_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout
```

should be `extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract`. Otherwise, you'll get an error concerning `mvcSuccessfulActionOnly`.